# How to get number of days (falling in February) in 5th week of year 2018

Tags: r, date

I am working on task where I need to get number of days falling in a particular week in a month.
Ex - In 5th week of 2018 - January has 3 days and february has 4 days.
How can I get Month (January, February) and number of days (3,4 respectively)

Answer (score 1):

An approach with `as.Date` and `table`:

```
year <- 2018
weeknumber <- 5
ENDDATE <- as.Date(paste(year, weeknumber, 1, sep="-"), "%Y-%U-%u")
table(format.Date(seq(ENDDATE-7, ENDDATE-1, 1), "%b"))
Feb Jan 
  4   3
```

Answer (score 0):

A lubridate option

```
library(lubridate)
start_date <- "2018-01-01"
week_number <- 5

table(months(date(start_date) + weeks(week_number) - 1:7))

#February  January 
#       4        3 

week_number <- 9
table(months(date(start_date) + weeks(week_number) - 1:7))

#February    March 
#       3        4
```